# Creating a chrome extension with react js, node js and mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, database, google-chrome-extension

Not sure if I have structured the question in the correct way.

However, I want to create a chrome extension that sends certain web requests while in usage, from the client device, so not on a separate server through the cloud, but for the front end and back end of the app to both run on the user's device on chrome, while there is also a dB. Is that possible? and if so, can I use React JS for the front end, Node JS and Express JS for the backend and then MySQL for the dB?

If I can't use these technologies, which ones would it be possible for me to do what I want?

Comment: Yes, a Chrome extension could talk with a Node.js server running locally.

Comment: @AKX so if I created it and it all ran on the same port, it would work fine? And would the MySQL work as normal?

Comment: Your extension (frontend) is just static files, no port there. MySQL runs on port 3306 by default, and you would choose some port for the backend server.

Comment: if they all run on the same port, would the front end and back end count as 2 separate servers or would they be a single one?

Comment: Your extension would not have a server. The frontend app, e.g. an extension popup, is just static files.

Comment: so where for example an ad blocker extension runs the code that actually blocks the ads? because I am assuming it has more than just a few static files. Unless I am misunderstand something here

Comment: An ad blocker would use e. g. the https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/ API from a Javascript file (which is still a static file).